# Package subfig and labels with \cref don't work

Tags: subfloats, cleveref

I have some problems with `subfig` package.

When I try to use `\subfloat` , it begins the numbering of the figure with 2 and the lable `\cref` in the text is not at all being recognized.
I have tried everything but those doesn't work. I would be very thankful for each help

```
%% Preambel
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman,a4paper]{scrreprt} % Dokumentart: Bericht, Papierformat: A4
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Suche im PDF nach Umlaute
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Codierung des Dokuments: Umlaute und Sonderzeichen
\usepackage{babel} % Sprachpaket
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{varioref}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\addbibresource{Literatur_Projektarbeit.bib}

%% Dokument
\begin{document}
Nach eine elektrophoretische Trennung der Serumproteine auf einem
Cellulose-Acetat-Gelträger erfolgte die Gelfärbung. Die Proteinbanden werden
mit Amido-Schwarz in dunkel-blau \cref{fig:gelAmidoschwarz}  oder mit Ponceau S 
in hell-rosa \cref{fig:gelPonceau} eingefärbt. Anschließend wurde das Gel
fotografisch mit einem Densitometer, Scanner oder Kamera aufgezeichnet. Eine
Software analysiert die Intensität den einzelnen Proteinbanden und berechnet
die relative Menge der vorhandenen Proteinen. Die erzielte Ergebnisse wurden
in Kuvendiagramm umgewandelt, digital gespeichert und mittels eines Druckers
    auf Papier übertragen.
        \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Gelfärbung mit Amido-Schwarz\label{fig:gelAmidoschwarz}]{%
        \includegraphics[height=7cm]{1_a_gel_amidoschwarz}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[Gelfärbung mit Ponceau S\label{fig:gelPonceau}]{%
        \includegraphics[height=7cm]{1_b_gel_ponceau}}
        \caption{Fraktionen-Elektrophorese auf Cellulose-Acetat-Träger. Dargestellt sind die Proteinbanden}
        \label{fig:gelFaerbungen}
        \end{figure}
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should try with `subfigure` environment, from `subcaption`.

Comment: Please give me more details

Comment: I've tested and there seems to be problems  also  with `subcaption`. I'll make other tests tomorrow, if no one else has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subfig` package is fully compatible with the `cleveref` package. The issue you're experiencing is *not* related to a conflict between these two packages. Instead, it's related to an incorrect loading order of the `varioref`, `hyperref`, and `cleveref` packages: they must be loaded in this order, *and no other*. It's also a good idea to load them last.

```
%% Preambel
%% remove 'demo' option in real document
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman,a4paper,demo]{scrreprt} % Dokumentart: Bericht, Papierformat: A4
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Suche im PDF nach Umlaute
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Codierung des Dokuments: Umlaute und Sonderzeichen
\usepackage{babel} % Sprachpaket
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{tgheros}

% load the next three packages last, in this order
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
%\addbibresource{Literatur_Projektarbeit.bib}

%% Dokument
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example

\cref{fig:gelAmidoschwarz}

\cref{fig:gelPonceau}

\cref{fig:gelFaerbungen}

\begin{figure}
\centering
        \subfloat[Gelfärbung mit Amido-Schwarz\label{fig:gelAmidoschwarz}]{%
        \includegraphics[height=7cm]{1_a_gel_amidoschwarz}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[Gelfärbung mit Ponceau S\label{fig:gelPonceau}]{%
        \includegraphics[height=7cm]{1_b_gel_ponceau}}

\caption{Fraktionen-Elektrophorese auf Cellulose-Acetat-Träger. Dargestellt sind die Proteinbanden}
\label{fig:gelFaerbungen}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```